# Access current_user from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

You may have heard of Pundit. https://github.com/elabs/pundit Basically, it's an authorization gem.

What I want to know is, how does it access the variable `current_user` inside its classes?

I don't know how, but `@user` and `user` are both equal somehow to the `current_user`

```
class PostPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @user = user
    @post = post
  end

  def update?
    user.admin? or not post.published?
  end
end
```

We also have the post variable inside this class. We can access this by running

```
def publish
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
end
```

in an action.

To install Pundit you need to include the module to the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include Pundit
end
```

**However, I still can't see how the class "queries" the controller for the current_user and how authorize gives the variable (post) to the class. Please answer these two questions :)**

Answer (score 0):

The `PostPolicy` class doesn't query anything.

The `authorize` method is a controller instance method, so it can just call `current_user`. You've passed it `@post`, which it uses to determine which policy class to use. Then it creates a new instance of that class, passing `current_user` and `@post` through.